# What is the Purpose of placeholders (e.g. %k, %f) in some GnuPG options?

Tags: gnupg

In some GnuPG options (`--cert-notation`, `--sig-notation`, `--photo-viewer` and others) there can be used certain placeholders (for instance %k, %f etc.).

What is the purpose of using that placeholders? In which programs are they expanded?

Answer (score 1):

Using those placeholders is especially helpful if you define such notations in your GnuPG configuration (`~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`). These placeholders get replaced by GnuPG just before the notation is applied (or the photo viewer called, ...) to be able to insert some information on the current operation. From `man gpg`:

> There are special codes that may be used in notation names. "%k" will be expanded into the key ID of the key being signed, "%K" into the long  key  ID  of  the  key  being
>                 signed, "%f" into the fingerprint of the key being signed, "%s" into the key ID of the key making the signature, "%S" into the long key ID of the key making the signature,
>                 "%g" into the fingerprint of the key making the signature (which might be a subkey), "%p" into the fingerprint of the primary key of the key  making  the  signature,  "%c"
>                 into  the signature count from the OpenPGP smartcard, and "%%" results in a single "%". %k, %K, and %f are only meaningful when making a key signature (certification), and
>                 %c is only meaningful when using the OpenPGP smartcard.

For example, consider you're running some certification service and host a website with further details on the certification of each key. If you want to append a notation containing a URL to further information on the signed key (without any discussion on how to achieve that), you could add following to your `gpg.conf`:

```
cert-notation details@cert.example.com=https://cert.example.com/lookup/%K
```

If you now sign a key `4E1F799AA4FF2279`, following notation will be appended:

```
details@cert.example.com=https://cert.example.com/lookup/4E1F799AA4FF2279
```